# MongoDB/Multer Query DB then upload File

Tags: ajax, mongodb, express, multer

I want to query a database and if result is found upload a file. At the moment it's the other way around. First the image is uploaded then the db is searched and updated.

A value I need, cid(req.body.cid), can only be accessed after upload() is called so that kinda complicates things, this is my current, working, code :

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({
    dest: './public/images/usercontent',
    limits: {
        files: 1,
        fields: 1,
        fileSize: 10000
    },
    fileFilter: function fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
        if (file.mimetype !== 'image/png' && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg') {
            req.multerImageValidation = 'wrong type';
            return cb(null, false);
        }
        return cb(null, true);
    }
}).single('uploads[]');

router.post('/uploadimg', isLoggedIn, function(req, res, next) {
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') {
                return res.send({
                    statusText: 'fileSize'
                });
            }
            return res.send({
                statusText: 'failed'
            });
        }
        if (req.multerImageValidation) {
            return res.send({
                statusText: 'wrongType'
            });
        }
        Company.findOneAndUpdate({
            ownedBy: req.user.local.username,
            _id: req.body.cid // value that is sent with the image
        }, {
            icon: 'images/usercontent/' + req.file.filename
        }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send({
                    statusText: 'failed'
                });
            }
            if (!result) {
                return res.send({
                    statusText: 'failed'
                });
            }
            res.send({
                statusText: 'success'
            });
        });
      //
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the success callback for the db query to upload image and then use the success callback of the upload image function to update the db record with cid? At a very high level, this would be:

```
  query db for record
   //if record found, in success callback
   attempt to upload image
       //if image uploaded successfully and cid generated, in success callback
       update db record
```

You can use the mongo **update** operation to ensure atomic operation